# Is it better to use -> instead of . in to implement `copyWithZone:` method in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nscopying

Say there's a class A with property p1, and setter for p1 has been overwritten. Now I want to implement NSCopying protocol for class A.

In my understanding since you're "copying" an instance of class A, there's no need to trigger any setter methods in `copyWithZone:` method. So `copyOfInstance -> _p1 = _p1;` is better than `copyOfInstance.p1 = _p1`. Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are forming the new object exactly as if you were implementing an initializer. So the rules are the same. Just as you must not use a setter method in an `init...` method, so you must not use a setter in `copyWithZone:`.

Comment: Thanks! BTW I always use self. to set the variables in init. New lesson learned. :)

Comment: One of my concern is that the -> symbol used in the question description. It's my first time using it, I was not sure whether it's right.